# Is it possible for any Linux distro to boot from an iMac Pro's internal SSD?

Tags: linux, macintosh

*tl; dr:* **Has anyone succeeded in installing *any* Linux distro to boot from an iMac Pro's internal SSD?**

The majority of my work occurs in Linux. I use my iMac Pro for running VMs, editing code and uploading information to remote servers. I would like to dispense with MacOS altogether and boot natively into Linux from the internal SSD.

I cannot locate the instructions or an ISO that installs Linux to boot from the internal SSD on an iMac Pro.

Apparently the T2 controller chip prevents 'unauthorized' operating systems from accessing internal storage.

Instructions for installing Linux onto other Mac models containing a T2 chip have not worked for me. I have disabled system integrity protection and secure boot. I am able to boot into *some* installer images from USB/ISO, but I never see the internal SSD as an installation destination.

If anyone has successfully installed any Linux distro onto the internal SSD of an iMac Pro, please tell me how you did it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a manual how to install Arch Linux although if you understand Linux you can install any other distro with a recent enough kernel (>=5.4):

https://geeks-world.github.io/articles/472106/

The T2 chip is not a problem once you disable Secure Boot.

Also refer to https://github.com/Dunedan/mbp-2016-linux

Comment: Many links in that manual are broken or in Russian, which unfortunately I am not fluent in. That manual specifically references **2018 MacBook Pros**. I was looking for instructions specific to the iMac Pro. There are significant hardware differences between the two. I have attempted to install distros with recent kernel versions, but never was presented with the internal SSD as an installation option

Comment: Running Linux on latest Macs is not recommended anyways: https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=22976502

Comment: When Apple discontinues MacOS updates for Intel hardware, I will require a Linux alternative, regardless of what is or is not recommended.